# How to cast literal type in string format "Integer" in its original format that is Integer

Tags: java

I have have same structure of objects from JSON or XML format:

| name | type | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | Float | ... |

```
{"name": "xyz", "type": "Float", ...}
```

I have maybe more than 50 objects that have this same structure, but if I want to push them to the database, I need the appropriate type of `T`, not in String.

Common generic class to all object in JSON and XML files (except for `private T value` property that is not in these files):

```
public class Resource<T> extends BaseModel {
    ...
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private T value;     // this one is not in json or xml files
    ...
}
```

In the `private T value;`, the type of T is in the `private String type` property.

In a switch case a need to cast `T` to the right type:

```
switch(type) {
    case "String":
       // cast T to String
    break;
    case "Integer":
       // cast T to Integer
    break;
    case "Float":
       // cast T to Float
    break;
    ...
```

}

After deserialization, how can I construct the object with the associate/cast of `T` to `Float`? Is it possible?

Or is there better way to approach this?

Comment: Isn't it possible using `Object value` instead of `T value`?

Comment: In order to cast, `T` would have to actually be that type.  I think what you really want to do is parse the XML into the type.  Strings use `BufferedReader` or `DataInputStream`, primitives use methods on their respective class counterparts, like `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What part of the above is not working? Just parse in the switch and you are good, no?

Comment: @GauthamM I don't know because I thought there was no difference between the two. Any examples or link to what you refer?

Comment: @LarsWissler Well I think you are right, there is no issues with this because the switch case is handling the possible cases...  I wasn't sure to go that direction, I'll give a try then I close my question if need it.

Comment: Usually in programming the simplest and most understandable path is best ;) Its not like the datatypes change so there will not be any maintenance cost attached to just writing a big hardcoded switch, so there is no benefit in saving lines and fancy logic.

Comment: @Sinan  There are differences. If you use `Object` then it could hold any type. Even though generics could also hold any type, as soon as you create `Resource<Float>` the `value` will be of type `Float` only. Also please mention whether `value` is also received as part of the json or xml

Comment: @Sinan Also you have mentioned `After deserialization, how can I construct the object ...`. But the object would be constructed "as part of the" deserialization process. So after the deserialization process, the object would already be present. You just have to set the appropriate `value` to that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `value` as an `Object` type, instead of using generics:

```java
public class Resource extends BaseModel {
    ...
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Object value;     // this one is not in json or xml files
    ...
}
```

So in the switch statement you could just do:

```java
Resource r = // object after deserialization...
Object value;
switch (r.getType()) {
    case "String":
        value = "test";
        break;
    case "Integer":
        value = Integer.valueOf(3);
        break;
    case "Float":
        value = Float.valueOf(5.3f);
        break;
    default:
        value = null;
}

r.setValue(value);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
FavoriteType fType = new FavoriteType();

switch(expression) {
    case "String":
       // cast T to String
        fType.put(String.class, new String("text"));
        String favoriteString = fType.get(String.class);
        break;
    case "Integer":
       // cast T to Integer
        fType.put(Integer.class, new Integer("1234"));
        Integer favoriteInteger = fType.get(Integer.class);
        break;
    case "Float":
       // cast T to Float
        fType.put(Float.class, new Float("1234.5"));
        Float favoriteFloat = fType.get(Float.class);
        break;
   
}



class FavoriteType {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

    public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(map.get(clazz));
    }

    public <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, T favorite) {
        map.put(clazz, favorite);
    }
}
```